# QgisInterface.addVectorLayer Error

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I am Esri-trained, trying to move into QGIS using Python.  Simply trying to add a vector layer in QGIS returns the below error:

`TypeError: QgisInterface.addVectorLayer(QString, QString, QString): first argument of unbound method must have type 'QgisInterface'`

Here's my code:

```
layer = qgis.core.QgsVectorLayer("C:\mypath\mypath\GTM_adm1.shp", "GTM_adm1", "ogr")
qgis.gui.QgisInterface.addVectorLayer(layer, "GTM_adm1", "ogr")
```

Not sure what I'm missing here but the Vector layer object is in the registry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try simply:

```
layer = iface.addVectorLayer("/path/to/shapefile/file.shp", "layer_name_you_like", "ogr")
```

Here you have a nice guide for PyQGIS: http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html

Comment: thanks, this worked fine.  But might you offer a quick explanation as to why my code returned an error?  The logic is not obvious to me.

Comment: Your method wants as first argument an instance of class. Here I found a nice explanation: https://julien.danjou.info/blog/2013/guide-python-static-class-abstract-methods

Comment: thanks, for the link.  It's a very useful explanation and has helped clarify some concepts for me.

Answer (score 4):

Just as a remark: `QgisInterface` is an abstract class and has virtual functions so it may not be instantiated, i.e. it defines an interface and not a complete implementation. But you can use `QgisInterface` class within a standalone application where the `iface` class is not available. There you can reimplement and override the main functions of the class. An example very trivial is the following:

```py
from qgis.core import QgsMapLayerRegistry, QgsVectorLayer
from qgis.gui import QgisInterface

def addVectorLayer(uri, provider, name):
    vl = QgsVectorLayer(uri, name, provider)
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vl)
    return vl, name

class MyIface(QgisInterface):
    def __init__(self):
        QgisInterface.__init__(self)

    def addVectorLayer(self, path, name, provider):
        return addVectorLayer(path, provider, name)

# usage:
# >>> myiface = MyIface()
# >>> myiface.addVectorLayer("some_path_to_layer", "some_name", "ogr")
```

So using

```
>>> myiface.addVectorLayer("some_path_to_layer", "some_name", "ogr")
(<qgis._core.QgsVectorLayer object at 0x7546440>, 'some_name')
```

it will work, but another method e.g

```
>>> myiface.activeLayer()
NotImplementedError: QgisInterface.activeLayer() is abstract and must be overridden
```

will raise to `NotImplementedError` because that method is defined into the class but it is not re-implemented, i.e. it is an abstract method.

BTW: your error (*...first argument of unbound method...*) is a different error though, the origin of the error is you don't have instantiated the class before, so the correct way to write was:

```
qgis.gui.QgisInterface().addVectorLayer(layer, "GTM_adm1", "ogr")
```

which would raise to `TypeError: qgis._gui.QgisInterface represents a C++ abstract class and cannot be instantiated`

Hope this helps as explanation.